# Translate R reshape into dcast

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

Hello and sorry if I am repeating myself, but I simply cannot wrap my head around moving from reshape to dcast. I have a small dataset:

```
        Val    relation   t
1  621.4035   unrelated  34
2  626.4485   unrelated  50
3  633.3349   unrelated  67
4  611.2006      opaque  34
5  626.5934      opaque  50
6  619.5182      opaque  67
7  607.2469 transparent  34
8  603.8099 transparent  50
9  594.7042 transparent  67
```

And this works nicely:

```
reshape(interact, timevar='relation', idvar='t',
    direction='wide')
```

Now, for some reasons I am getting errors if I try to use dcast from reshape2 package and I do not understand why. Can anyone show me how to translate reshape?

Many thanks, PM

Comment: What error are you getting? Where's the `dcast` code that didn't work? What is your desired output?

Comment: I get almost similar results to `reshape` method using `dcast(interact, t~relation, value.var="Val")` without any `errors`